# Upload file using Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I have a form where video can be uploaded and sent to remote destination. I have a cURL request which I want to 'translate' to PHP using Guzzle.

So far I have this:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $file     = $request->file('file');
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $realPath = $file->getRealPath();

        $client   = new Client();
        $response = $client->request('POST', 'http://mydomain.de:8080/spots', [
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name'     => 'spotid',
                    'country'  => 'DE',
                    'contents' => file_get_contents($realPath),
                ],
                [
                    'type' => 'video/mp4',
                ],
            ],
        ]);

        dd($response);

    }
```

This is cURL which I use and want to translate to PHP:

```
curl -X POST -F 'body={"name":"Test","country":"Deutschland"};type=application/json' -F 'file=@C:\Users\PROD\Downloads\617103.mp4;type= video/mp4 ' http://mydomain.de:8080/spots
```

So when I upload the video, I want to replace this hardcoded

**C:\Users\PROD\Downloads\617103.mp4**.

When I run this, I get an error:

> Client error: `POST http://mydomain.de:8080/spots` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: request body invalid: expecting form value 'body`'
>
> Client error: `POST http://mydomain.de/spots` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
>       request body invalid: expecting form value 'body'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd review the Guzzle's [`multipart`](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#multipart) request options. I see two issues:

1. The JSON data needs to be stringified and passed with the same name you're using in the curl request (it's confusingly named `body`).
2. The `type` in the curl request maps to the header `Content-Type`. From `$ man curl`:

   > You can also tell curl what Content-Type to use by using 'type='.

Try something like:

```php
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://mydomain.de:8080/spots', [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'body',
            'contents' => json_encode(['name' => 'Test', 'country' => 'Deutschland']),
            'headers'  => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'file',
            'contents' => fopen('617103.mp4', 'r'),
            'headers'  => ['Content-Type' => 'video/mp4']
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

- While using the `multipart` option, make sure you are not passing `content-type` => `application/json` :)
- If you want to POST form fields AND upload file together, just use this `multipart` option. It's an array of arrays where `name` is form field name and it's value is the POSTed form value. An example:

```
'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'attachments[]', // could also be `file` array
                    'contents' => $attachment->getContent(),
                    'filename' => 'dummy.png',
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'username',
                    'contents' => $username
                ]
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

if the php is on the target server then`filename` is required !